# k-means and (re?) standardisation of a sub-set

Tags: data-transformation, k-means, standardization, subset

I have data which is customer purchases of items in each of three months:

- I have summed the data over the three months for each customer;
- calculated the proportion of purchases that each item represents for each customer;
- applied an arcsin-square root transformation to correct for skewness;
- applied a range transformation to ensure all variables are on the scale 0 to 1;
- done a k means on the resultant data.

This gives me 9 clusters and hence 9 centres, based on arcsin, range standardised variables. The clusters are well defined in terms of the various purchase patterns that can take place, eg a pattern for fast food, vegetarians, etc. I can allocated a customer to each cluster.

I now subset the data by each of the three months. I want to find which of the now defined 9 clusters each customer in each month is closest to - I am interested in if customers move between clusters over time. So, for each monthly subset I again calculate a proportion and apply an arcsin-square root transformation to begin to get my sub-setted version of the data close to that which was used for clustering.

My question now is to either:

1. range standardise on the range in this new, sub-setted, data; or
2. range standardise on the range in the original aggregated version of the data?

With (1) the range of the variables in the sub-set is 0 to 1, whilst with (2) it is inside/outside the range 0 to 1.  I am unsure which is the correct/"best" approach to take.